# Convert String with commas and floating point to Double

Tags: c#, type-conversion, double

I'm trying to convert some strings to double value 
here is the short version of the code (the important line):

```
double.Parse(xlWorksheet.Cells[i, "R"].Text);
```

Examples of Strings Values that gives an exception:

```
116,900.2               
202,893.28             
145.98                    
604.73     
8,668.21          
4,335.98
```

By the way

```
xlWorksheet.Cells[i, "R"].Text
```

Is Equal to one of the examples i wrote that gives an exception
Someone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is the exception? what is the value of `xlWorksheet.Cells[i, "R"].Text`? are all those values in a single string, or each string contains a single value? You should show an example of a specific string input

Comment: @Habib why remove commas? double.Parse can handle commas...

Comment: If xlWorksheet.Cells[i, "R"].Text is a string in the correct format (for example:  "16,900.2", "202,893.28", "145.98", "604.73", "8,668.21", "4,335.98"), then it should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes i try it and it gives and exception Input String not in format

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
Convert.ToDouble("123131312 ".Trim());
```

Comment: it doesn't work the strings are given with dots and commas

Comment: add .replace(".","") for all characters

Comment: but then it will change the value of the input?

Comment: try to find if there is any return key char or special char in the input cell; eg; char(10), char(13) or char(10) + char(13) etc.

Comment: Never mind i find a solution using regular expression thanks anyway